# options for producing audio with GWT

Tags: gwt, audio, html

What options are there for producing audio in a GWT app?  I'm thinking of making a simple game, but I'm disappointed to see that there's still not much progress on audio support directly in GWT (yes, I realize that's largely due to lack of underlying browser support; looking forward to HTML5!)

[This blog post](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/03/giving-your-gwt-application-voice.html) says that "audio support in GWT is rapidly evolving", yet I don't see updates in over a year, at least not at that site.  It seems these are the available options:

- [GWT Voices](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-voices/)
- [GWT SoundManager](http://www.codelathe.com/gwtsm/)
- [GWT Sound](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-sound/)
- <strike>[GWT Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/)</strike>  (all of the audio APIs seem deprecated here)

I believe most of these (all of them?) rely on Flash to produce audio.  I'm most inclined to go with the GWT Incubator, as that's where features slated for inclusion in GWT get started, but I've no real recommendations to go on.  I would appreciate hearing about your experiences with any of these libraries, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT Voices is written by Fred Sauer. He seems to be very closely affiliated with GWT. I've used his drag and drop code before, and found it quite well documented and frequently updated. Also, he seems responsive to questions in the forum. (I have no affiliation!)

I don't know anything about the others.

Comment: Ditto for me on Fred's code.  I used his drag & drop and logging code in a calendar app; great stuff.

Comment: I agree as well. I am currently using GWT voices in an app that I am working on to produce sounds when users receive IM's or their presence changes, etc.

It does not rely completely on Flash to produce audio as far as I know. In any event I would definitely recommend it, the API is nice and simple and it works really nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately, gwt-voices lacks pause support, so I'll be moving on to something different after an entire day of messing with it :(

Answer (score 3):

Most of the aforementioned SoundManager2 wrappers are dated and no longer supported. Gwt Voices is a good project, but lacks a lot of the functionality that is provided by a mature and proven solution like SoundManager2.

Check out this newer one called gwt-soundmanager2. It's a fork from Jeffery Miller's gwt-sound project. https://github.com/rcaloras/gwt-soundmanager2

(I created it, happy to answer questions or add additional features)

Comment: Haven't needed to update it in a while. :) Should be pretty straight forward to update the version of SoundManager2 or GWT though if needed. Please give it a shot and post an issue on github if something is failing because it's dated. Thanks!